# Cucumber cuke examples syntax

Tags: cucumber

Folks,

I am stuck in one place, looks like a syntax error, here is my cuke:

```
Feature: This is a test feature

         @stagingsearch
         Scenario Outline: Create a search and run it
                   When I create a search for profile "profilesame" for user <user>
                   Then I should see "Results"

        Examples: These are the users
        | user |
        | mol_2_1 |
        | mol_2_2 |
```

I get the error saying implement step:

```
When /^I create a search for profile "([^"]*)" for user mol_(\d+)_(\d+)$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

What I dont understand is why cucumber is not parsing examples mol_2_1 as a single string. There are just 2 arguments here but cucumber seems to be confused and takes it as 3 arguments.

Comment: I think for some reason cucumber is having problems with the underscore _ in the examples, not sure how i can escape that.

Comment: Cucumber assumes each digit is a separate argument. Justin's suggestion should work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are asking what is the regex you need to implement the step, rather than how to make Cucumber's suggestion correct?

If that assumption is correct, the step you want is:

```
When /^I create a search for profile "([^"]*)" for user (.*)$/ do |profile, user|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```